# How set paramètres Images in docker-compose and dockerfile and build and execution

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i want to build my image docker separately and add tag with date of execution for do back-up and rollback easy.
i want do

> docker-compose up -d --build-arg server=server_dev_20200909, client=client_dev_20200909

```html
version: '3'
services:
 mongo:
  image: mongo:4.4
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - mongoData:/data/dbmongo

 server:
  ports:
    - "9090:8000"
  env_file: server/local.env
  image: ${server}
  links:
  - mongo
  volumes: 
    - reports:/reports
  restart: always

 webapp-client:
  ports:
  - "8000:80"
  image: ${client}
  restart: always
  env_file:
    - webapp-client/.env
  links: 
    - server
    
volumes: 
    mongoData:
    reports:
```

and try to give ARG in my build image but don't work

```html
# a default value
ARG  ENV_BUILD
# étape de build
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app/webapp-client
COPY ./webapp-client .
RUN npm install
RUN echo ${ENV_BUILD}
RUN npm run build:${ENV_BUILD}


# étape de production
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/webapp-client/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

> docker build --build-arg ENV_BUILD=dev -t client_dev_20200909_1208 -f webapp-client/Dockerfile .

```html
Step 11/16 : RUN echo ${ENV_BUILD}
 ---> Running in 36b4a81503a9

Removing intermediate container 36b4a81503a9
 ---> f3305f424fb5
Step 12/16 : RUN npm run build:${ENV_BUILD}
 ---> Running in 78932dd8ee1d
npm ERR! missing script: build:
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     build
npm ERR!     build:dev

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-09-09T15_13_07_620Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build:${ENV_BUILD}' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm a little confused by your files so permit me to give you what I hope is the solution:

You can either provide `build-arg` to a `docker build` or `docker-compose build`.

#### `docker build`

Your `Dockerfile` would need to contain, e.g.:

```
ARG SERVER="M"
ARG CLIENT="N"
...
RUN echo "Server=${SERVER}; Client=${CLIENT}
```

> **NOTE** CAPITALIZATION of env variables is **not** required but is good practice

Then you could run `docker-build` using these defaults or override (not necessary) with `build-arg` flags:

```sh
docker build --build-arg=SERVER=X --build-arg=CLIENT=Y ...
```

E.g.:

```sh
docker build \
--tag=63814651 \
--file=./Dockerfile \
.

Step 1/4 : FROM busybox
Step 2/4 : ARG SERVER="M"
Step 3/4 : ARG CLIENT="N"
Step 4/4 : RUN echo "Server=${SERVER}; Client=${CLIENT}"
Server=M; Client=N
```

Or:

```sh
docker build \
--build-arg=SERVER=X --build-arg=CLIENT=Y
--tag=63814651 \
--file=./Dockerfile \
.

Step 1/4 : FROM busybox
Step 2/4 : ARG SERVER="M"
Step 3/4 : ARG CLIENT="N"
Step 4/4 : RUN echo "Server=${SERVER}; Client=${CLIENT}"
Server=X; Client=Y
```

> **NOTE** IIUC you must flag each `build-arg` separately

> **NOTE** `SERVER` and `CLIENT` overridden in second example

#### `docker-compose build`

I will check whether you can avoid the duplication but, for transparency:

```
version: '3'
services:
 something:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    args:
    - SERVER=X
    - CLIENT=Y
  image: something
  restart: always
...
```

Then you could run `docker-compose build` using these defaults or override (not necessary) with `build-arg` flags:

```sh
docker-compose build --build-arg=SERVER=A --build-arg=CLIENT=B ...
```

E.g.:

> **NOTE** commenting out `args`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  something:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      # args:
      # - SERVER=X
      # - CLIENT=Y
    image: something
```

Then:

```sh
docker-compose \
--file=./docker-compose.yaml \
build --no-cache

Step 1/4 : FROM busybox
Step 2/4 : ARG SERVER="M"
Step 3/4 : ARG CLIENT="N"
Step 4/4 : RUN echo "Server=${SERVER}; Client=${CLIENT}"
Server=M; Client=N
```

> **NOTE** Values are from `Dockerfile` defaults

```
version: "3"
services:
  something:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
      - SERVER=X
      - CLIENT=Y
    image: something
```

Then:

```sh
docker-compose \
--file=./docker-compose.yaml \
build --no-cache

Step 1/4 : FROM busybox
Step 2/4 : ARG SERVER="M"
Step 3/4 : ARG CLIENT="N"
Step 4/4 : RUN echo "Server=${SERVER}; Client=${CLIENT}"
Server=X; Client=Y
```

> **NOTE** Values are from `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  something:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      # args:
      #   - SERVER=X
      #   - CLIENT=Y
    image: something
```

Then:

```sh
docker-compose \
--file=./docker-compose.yaml \
build \
--build-arg=SERVER=A --build-arg=CLIENT=B \
--no-cache

Step 1/4 : FROM busybox
Step 2/4 : ARG SERVER="M"
Step 3/4 : ARG CLIENT="N"
Step 4/4 : RUN echo "Server=${SERVER}; Client=${CLIENT}"
Server=A; Client=B
```

> **NOTE** Values are from command-line

And, for completeness:

```
version: "3"
services:
  something:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
      - SERVER=X
      - CLIENT=Y
    image: something
```

Then:

```sh
docker-compose \
--file=./docker-compose.yaml \
build \
--build-arg=SERVER=A --build-arg=CLIENT=B \
--no-cache

Step 1/4 : FROM busybox
Step 2/4 : ARG SERVER="M"
Step 3/4 : ARG CLIENT="N"
Step 4/4 : RUN echo "Server=${SERVER}; Client=${CLIENT}"
Server=A; Client=B
```

> **NOTE** command-line always beats defaults

Comment: think for or answer.
You have response how set arg in build image.
but i still the question run specifically with my image version or time.
 i don't want use build options  in my docker compose. but launch image set in pararmeters

Comment: `build-args` are only applicable at build time. For run time variables, you will need to use environment variables. These may be referenced in `Dockerfile` using `ENV` but be careful to use `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` shell form if you require environment variables to be evaluated with these commands. Similarly use `--env=` on the command-line